# How to deploy a scalable pyflink "app" the right way?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

We want to keep things simple and use python wherever possible. Thus we want to use [pyflink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/python/overview/) (latest version, we are flexible) for [continuous queries](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/sql/gettingstarted/).

We have written the code (which pulls live data from a pulsar cluster with the [flink-pulsar connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/pulsar/) ). Now, a few conceptual questions to this?

- How can we deploy (Session Deployment) this code as/to Flink Task Managers so that we are able to scale? Assuming, that with every message that arrives we updated the continuous query. If there is a lot of inbound messages, we would want to have multiple K8s workers to run a pod with that Flink code. What is a good concept to do so? (we would set the [pulsar subscription type to exclusive](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.0.x/concepts-messaging/#subscription-types), so that only one Flink instance would consume that latest message and then compute on that one).
- And how do we deploy the Flink Job Manager and let it know of all the Task Manger instances on-the-fly? How do you configure it?
- Assuming we understand how to deploy in a scalable way, what would be the preferred way of publishing result from this distributed approach? Pushing continuous queries results to a [sink topic in pulsar](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/pulsar/#pulsar-sink)? The goal is to send the results over SSE to consumer clients.

Any hints/documentation to a full tutorial of pyflink for a scalable deployment with Job and Task manager is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this question I've made can help you in some bit? It shows how to use the kubernetes operator to deploy pyflink (provided you have already used it in your Session Deployment). So far I am still unable to add connectors (like kafka/kinesis/others) to use it on my python job, if you find a way to add the connectors let me know!. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759718/flink-not-reading-kinesis-connector-on-python

Comment: Sorry wrong link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764406/deploying-pyflink-on-kubernetes-with-connectors-kafka-kinesis