# Deploying pyflink on kubernetes with connectors (kafka/kinesis)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I am trying to find a way to deploy pyflink on k8s using the k8s operator. I have been able to upload a job already with the k8s Operator, but I can't find how to add connectors to it (Like kafka-connector.jar o kinesis-connector.jar). I couldn't find anymore documentation on how to use pyflink with k8s operators and I am not familiar with java. So it's a dead-end to me

I am basing myself [on this repo](https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/examples/flink-python-example/python-example.yaml) which states to use a FlinKDeployment.yaml to deploy a demo pyflink which sinks to console (assuming there's a k8s cluster with the operator already running to apply it to). I have followed it and it works. But now **I am just trying to figure out how to add the source/sink connectors .jar on it.**

I've followed the documentation on [how to use connectors in python](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/table/python_table_api_connectors/), which worked well locally. But not on the k8s operator for some reason.

The steps I have followed is to add the connector flink-sql-connector-kinesis-1.16.2.jar to my Dockerfile image, and on the python file (also included on the image) I added the code to reference it, this works well locally:

```
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.set_parallelism(1)
t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env)
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

t_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string(
    "pipeline.jars",
    "file:///" + CURRENT_DIR + "/lib/flink-sql-connector-kinesis-1.16.2.jar",
)
```

And then I create a sink table using kinesis

```
    t_env.execute_sql(    """ CREATE TABLE print_table (<columns...>)
          WITH (
            'connector' = 'kinesis',
            'stream' = '<stream_name>',
            'aws.region' = '<aws_region>',
            'sink.partitioner-field-delimiter' = ';',
            'sink.batch.max-size' = '100',
            'format' = 'json',
            'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
          )  """)
```

But when I make the FlinkDeployment based on that repo, I see it can't find Kinesis, probably because this is not the way to include the connector.jar in a pyflink job submitted with k8s operator that uses java rather than python I assume?? . The java error I get is  `Could not find any factory for identifier 'kinesis' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory' in the classpath.`

The way I am submitting my job is with this manifest based from that repo, and my python file inside the image is indeed found at `/opt/flink/usrlib/python_demo.py` :

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: python-kinesis-smoke
spec:
  image: <docker_hub_repo>/pyflink_kinesis:latest
  flinkVersion: v1_16
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "1"
  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  job:
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/opt/flink-python_2.12-1.16.1.jar # Note, this jarURI is actually a placeholder
    entryClass: "org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver"
    args: ["-pyclientexec", "/usr/local/bin/python3", "-py", "/opt/flink/usrlib/python_demo.py"]
    parallelism: 1
    upgradeMode: stateless
```

I have already read all the [Flink K8s Operator documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-release-0.1/docs/custom-resource/reference/#jobspec) and I couldn't find any mention to pyflink, only submitting jobs already packed entirely on .jar files which is not my use case since I am on pyflink. I also found this [other repo](https://github.com/spotify/flink-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/python_guide.md) about using a manifest of kind FlinkCluster but I couldn't make it work as the k8s cluster says a Kind FlinkCluster does not exists.

Has anyone some pointers as to how to deploy pyflink using connectors on k8s operator on Application or Session mode? I believe my only option would be to [submit with the CLI](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/cli/#submitting-pyflink-jobs) which I would like to avoid in favor of using the k8s operator if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can bake the jars in your Docker image and then pull them into the running script by using:

```
env.add_jars("file:///path/to/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.16.2.jar")
```

Details on this are reflected here: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/dependency_management/